# Android translate apply current fragment

Tags: android, fragment, spinner, locale, translation

I am trying to translate app, but current fragment did not apply changes after language chosen. In my Main Activity I got:

```
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        int check = 0;
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            check = check + 1;
            if(check>1) {
                switch ((int)id) {
                    case 0:
                        locale = new Locale("en");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        locale = new Locale("de");
                        break;
                }
                Locale.setDefault(locale);
                Configuration config = new Configuration();
                config.locale = locale;
                getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                       getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

                //recreate();
            }
        }
```

which will not refresh current fragment. If I use recreate -refresh activity, but redirect me to another fragment. Is it possible to refresh current fragment after another lang chosen?

Comment: Usually language is selected inside system's settings. The default locale will be picked according to system settings language.

Comment: @alexeypolusov How your comment helps/answers my question?